# Edit the bash .bashrc without the use of shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspberry-pi

I edited the file `.bashrc` on my raspberry and added `startx` at the end.

Does anyone know how to remove it without the use of a shell ? Obviously, every time I open a shell it calls `startx` and closes the shell afterwards.

Comment: Do you have an X session? Any graphical editors? Any existing shell sessions?

Comment: I have the standard text editor of raspbian, but gets permission errors if I want to edit the bash.bashrc. Also all other standard programs that comes with raspbian like the python shell, if it's any help.

Comment: If you can get a python prompt then you can just move the file out of the way to solve the problem.

Comment: ssh did it for me, but will try python the next time I change systems files..

Comment: The ssh some-other-shell solution is a better solution if it works. The python prompt/etc. are just other possible workarounds when that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you can ssh into your raspberry pi, if so try:

```
ssh -t username@hostname /bin/something-other-than-bash
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to sed:

```
ssh -t user@raspberry "sed -i '$d' .bashrc"
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use sftp to get the .bashrc.
- Some local editor to modify the file,
- then sftp again to put the file back.

Also see this post.

https://serverfault.com/questions/94503/login-without-running-bash-profile-or-bashrc

Answer (score 0):

`.bashrc` will execute when you open the `bash` shell. You can open any another shell (e.g. `tcsh`) and edit it.